# Can I set active_group in index.php in application folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have more then 1 user using same application folder. So they share database.php.

I have added all infos into $db[][] matrix. Now I need just to set $active_group in index.php file.

Not in controller, not in model.

Any ideas how to do this?

I have tried to add `$active_group = 'test';`  at start of index.php, tried at user config part, tried before loading bootstrap, tried at the end. Nothing worked.

My database.php

```
$active_group = "";
$active_record = TRUE;
// Ale
$db['ale']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['ale']['username'] = 'root';
$db['ale']['password'] = '';
$db['ale']['database'] = 'eo_ale';
$db['ale']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['ale']['dbprefix'] = 'ed_';
$db['ale']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['ale']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['ale']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['ale']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['ale']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['ale']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['ale']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['ale']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['ale']['stricton'] = FALSE;


// Sre
$db['sre']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['sre']['username'] = 'root';
$db['sre']['password'] = '';
$db['sre']['database'] = 'eo_sre';
$db['sre']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['sre']['dbprefix'] = 'ed_';
$db['sre']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['sre']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['sre']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['sre']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['sre']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['sre']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['sre']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['sre']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['sre']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

so what I want now is to create function that will when ale logs in, set $active_group="ale", or when sre logs in, to set $active_group = "sre".

This should not be that hard, but I can't find way to do this...

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not need much code, it's adding value to the $active_group variable.

Comment: You typically set active_group in config.php. Why do you want to do it in index.php?

Comment: I have multiple applications, every application share files, but has it's own database.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html `$DB1 = $this->load->database('db1');` and `$DB2 = $this->load->database('db2');` which can be done in the controller or model. There isn't a straightforward way to do it in index.php.

Comment: @stormdrain I have read that, it's way to use it when you have 1 application to use 2 or more databases. I have 1 app connected to 1 database. Same files. But if you run files as user Foo, you get foo database to use, if you run as Pew user, you get pew database to use. Application files are all the same. Only database params are different for each user.

Comment: `if($user == 'user1'){//use $DB2}`. What's the problem? To clarify: at the top of your model(s) you can set a variable like `$database` and depending on which user is in there you can assign `$database` by loading the appropriate database for the user (`$database = $this->load->database('user2');`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40140/discussion-between-lolrs2013-and-stormdrain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set `$active_group` in index.php as it will get overwritten when the database config file is loaded, but you can do something like this

add `define('ACTIVE_SITE', 'default_new');` to the index.php file

then in the database file change `$active_group` to

```
if (defined('ACTIVE_SITE')) {
    $active_group = ACTIVE_SITE;
} else {
    $active_group = 'default';
}
```

Comment: THX! Just a solution that I was seeking for. I have never thought of doing it with globals. TY VM!